# How to add nvidia-xrun sessions to SDDM?

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, kde

In SDDM there is an menu of sessions types (for example, it may be Plasma, XFCE and Openbox). Is there a way to add custom options here? For example, the same Plasma option but started with nvidia-xrun script?

For now i tried this:

1. Copied /usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop to plasma-nvidia.desktop and added Exec=/usr/bin/nvidia-xrun into it;
2. Added startkde to the end of file /etc/X11/xinit/nvidia-xinitrc;
3. Added my user to sudoers for commands tee and modprobe (they are used in nvidia-xrun script):

```
%bumblebee ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/tee,/usr/sbin/modprobe
```

I can choose Plasma-Nvidia in SDDM but when i try to insert password - SDDM freezes. LED on my laptop signalize that GPU is started but Plasma session never appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer another option.
You can make lvm partition with luks protection. And when you turn on the computer, the system will ask for the password from the lvm section, which will replace the password for the SDDM. Then create a systemd service with nvidia-xrun to start the plasma. I don't see another option now.